# Adding layout properties dynamically

Tags: android

I have added a `LinearLayout` dynamically and a `TextView` into it. Now I have to add the background, format them as per my requirement. So I am stuck with few questions. Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.master);
LinearLayout Linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
Linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
Linear1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
Linear1.setId(1);
TextView tvLeft = new TextView(this);
tvLeft.setText("Hello");
tvLeft.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Linear1.addView(tvLeft);
parentLayout.addView(Linear1);
```

I have few questions:

- How can I add drawable resource as my background?

I have tried this:

```
Linear1.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_pink));
```

I am getting error message by the compiler as:

> The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable)

- How to access the element whose id is set pragmatically?
- How to set width = 0dip?

Please help me with these question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_pink);
```

or

```
Linear1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_pink));
```

**How to access the element whose id is set pragmatically?**

with the `findViewById(yourid)`  itself

Comment: setId takes only integers. I have written setId(1) what should I write in findViewById?

Comment: findViewById also accepts int only... you should give `findViewById(1)`